# Decrypting a rclone backup locally

Tags: backup, rclone

I am using TrueNAS Cloud Sync Tasks to backup to Backblaze B2 nightly. I have the files set to be encrypted, but not filenames. Backblaze is configured to keep versions of the files.

Restoring the latest version of my file seems easy enough to do with a PULL Cloud Sync Task, but how about versioning, if I want to pull a specific version of the file.

I thought this would be a manual task, downloading the version required and decrypting said file, and this is where my struggles began.

rclone is used by TrueNAS to perform the backups.

On my local machine I ran:

```
rclone obscure [pass]
```

```
rclone obscure [salt]
```

```
rclone copyto file.txt.bin file.txt -v --crypt-remote=lc: --crypt-filename-encryption=off --crypt-directory-name-encryption=false --crypt-password=[obscured pass] --crypt-password2=[obscured salt]
```

Which seems to run fine however the contents of the file start RCLONE then what could conceivably be an elvish language under.

I did read to try pasting the obscured values from the NAS into my local command and try that but I cannot find them, it seems the CLI and WebUI use different files to store the data (WebUI in a DB?) and I am not sure what else to try.

Can anyone enlighten me to what I am doing wrong?

TIA